# Gradle does not calling default tasks of other module

Tags: java, gradle

I am working project structure like below

```
root/
    project-1/
         build.gradle
    project-2/
         build.gradle
build.gradle
settings.gradle
```

root/settings.gradle is look like below

```
include 'project-1'
include 'project-2'
```

project-1/build.gradle is like below

```
....

defaultTasks 'task1','task2','task3'
```

Here task3 does copies build file of project-1 to one of directory of project-2. Project-2 need this files for building.

project-2/build.gradle is like below

```
...

dependencies {
  compile 'xyx.jar'
  compile 'pqr.jar'
  implementation project(":project-1:defaultTasks")

}
```

When I build project-2, it does not build defaultTasks of project-1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can able to solve using gradle's ***compileJava*** task

project-1/build.gradle is look like

```
....

compileJava.dependsOn task3
task3.dependsOn task2
task2.dependsOn task1
```

and now project-2/build.gradle will look like

```
...

dependencies {
  compile 'xyx.jar'
  compile 'pqr.jar'
  compile 'project-1'
}
```

project-2 automatically build project-1 with all desired tasks

Answer (score 0):

The `defaultTasks` are just the tasks that are executed when `gradle` is called without any tasks as arguments.

If you want additional tasks to be executed when a project is used as an dependency of another project, you need to register those tasks as task dependencies of the tasks that build the respective project (e.g. `jar` or `assemble`)